# Customizing Sublime Text 2 to be like CodeRunner

Tags: python, sublimetext2, coderunner

I've been using Sublime Text for a while now, but I checked out CodeRunner and there are a 2 features I really like about it that I'd like to get working in Sublime.

1) Run / Custom Run command: I like in CodeRunner how it will determine the type of file from the extension (.py, .js) and run a terminal command in an embedded terminal. You can also customize the run command for your specific use.

2) Boilerplate code: When you create a new file of some time, CodeRunner has boilerplate code setup for you. I suppose I could try to so this with snippets, but is that the best way of going about it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try pressing `F7`? I Think that was the default to execute/run a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can customize the command to be launched according to the type of file by using [sublime build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html)

2) [Snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/snippets.html) looks indeed the best way to provide boilerplate code.

Comment: Sublime Text 2 > CodeRunner. I found this very helpful as well: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/perfect-workflow-in-sublime-text-free-course--net-27293